# Python Google Cloud Function Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

As detailed here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113672049

Cross-posted here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/5879)

I'm getting a connection reset error when using the Firebase Storage API from a Google Cloud Function in Python.

The deployed function is calling one blob-get i.e.

```
from firebase_admin import storage

def fn(request):
  bucket = 'my-firebase-bucket'
  path = '/thing'
  blob = storage.bucket(bucket).get_blob(path)
```

The failure is intermittent; the function has around a 90% success rate.

It seems more likely to fail the first time the function is called after it is deployed.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. I am using Google Storage. I set up a function to be triggered when a file is uploaded to a bucket. I uploaded 5719 files and 5551 were processed. Logs show "connection "reset by peer" error. Could you figure out how to go about it? If so please share.

Comment: Some suggest putting a timer, or a retry on ConnectionReset, but nobody's gotten to the bottom of it yet.  I've a feeling it's a low-level Python-C ConnectionPool race condition, and it'll be tricky to identify — but I'm just guessing. :)

Comment: I have also put a loop to finish up unprocessed files. But I have noticed that I am not getting that error any more if I transfer the files (to cloud storage) without using the -m option in gsutil. Plus they have mentioned that Python is beta while NodeJS is not, so we can expect this to get better with time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cloud functions are stateless, but can re-use global state from previous invocations. This is explained in [tips](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) and [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec).

Using global state with retries should give you a more robust function:

```py
from tenacity import retry, stop_after_attempt, wait_random
from firebase_admin import storage

@retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(3), wait=wait_random(min=1, max=2))
def get_bucket(storage):
    return storage.bucket('my-firebase-bucket')

@retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(3), wait=wait_random(min=1, max=2))
def get_blob(bucket, path):
    return bucket.get_blob(path)

bucket = get_bucket(storage)

def fn(request):
  path = '/thing'
  blob = get_blob(bucket, path)
  # etc..
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.  This is a great suggestion, and should be in the best-practices for anyone who wanders across this. I'll chalk this up as an answer to the question since the real answer seems to be workarounds such as these, as the source of the issue is quite deep in the bowels of Google Cloud.

Comment: +1 - just wanted to add that "retrying" seems to be unmaintained, but the issues page points to a more recently active fork called "tenacity": https://github.com/rholder/retrying/issues/65

Comment: Thanks @favq I updated the answer to use `tenacity`

Comment: Would it be more consistent to implement this with `from google.api_core import retry`?

Comment: I've tried using google.api_core.retry but I'm still getting errors. https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5879#issuecomment-549782962

Comment: firebase_admin module seems to contain a built-in retry handling (Search for Version 2.16.0 - February 21, 2019) https://firebase.google.cn/support/release-notes/admin/python

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check how many clients you are creating.

> Try to reuse network connections across function invocations, as
>   described in Optimizing Networking. However, note that a connection
>   that remains unused for 2 minutes might be closed by the system, and
>   further attempts to use a closed connection will result in a
>   **"connection reset" error**. Your code should either use a library that
>   handles closed connections well, or handle them explicitly if using
>   low-level networking constructs.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#network

See this example where they only create a client once and reuse it in functions:

```
import os
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

# Create a global Pub/Sub client to avoid unneeded network activity
pubsub = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()


def gcp_api_call(request):
    """
    HTTP Cloud Function that uses a cached client library instance to
    reduce the number of connections required per function invocation.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>.
    """

    project = os.getenv('GCP_PROJECT')
    request_json = request.get_json()

    topic_name = request_json['topic']
    topic_path = pubsub.topic_path(project, topic_name)

    # Process the request
    data = 'Test message'.encode('utf-8')
    pubsub.publish(topic_path, data=data)

    return '1 message published'
```

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/networking#accessing_google_apis