# AIOHTTP RetryClient on JSON Decode Errors

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to use the aiohttp_retry's RetryClient to address random JSON decoding errors, but it seems retries are not working. Can JSON decode errors be retried?

**ERROR - message='Attempt to decode JSON with unexpected mimetype: text/html; charset=utf-8'**

When I try to use debugging (latest community Pycharm), my app seems to get confused and errors out, but running straight through works, albeit with the decode error/exceptions still. Error rate is ~20 out of 3950 URI's in 20 minutes, but I want to alleviate manually fixing them afterwards.

`aiohttp 3.8.3`
`aiohttp_retry 2.8.3`
`Pythton 3.10`

`from aiohttp import TCPConnector`

`from aiohttp_retry import RetryClient, ExponentialRetry`

```
async def get_parcel_details(client, sem, url):
    async with sem, client.get(url) as resp:
        if resp.status == 200:
            try:
                parcel_details = await resp.json(encoding='UTF-8', content_type='application/json')
                return parcel_details

            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(str(e))
                await asyncio.sleep(2)
                logger.warning(f"sleeping on {url} for 2 seconds, retrying?")
                parcel_details = {'Owner': 'ERROR', 'Rental': False}

                return parcel_details
        else:
            logger.error(resp.status)
```

```
async def async_main(APNs: list):
    connector = TCPConnector(ssl=False, limit=15, limit_per_host=10, enable_cleanup_closed=True)
    async with RetryClient(headers=API_HEADER, connector=connector, raise_for_status=True,
                           retry_options=ExponentialRetry(attempts=3)) as retry_client:
        sem = asyncio.Semaphore(20)
        tasks = []
        for apn in APNs:
            parcel_url = f'https://api_endpoint/parcel/{apn}'
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(get_parcel_details(retry_client, sem, parcel_url)))

        parcels = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

        return parcels
```

I tried putting another get in the Exception, but made things worse.

Answer (score 0):

After reading post: [How to retry async requests upon ClientOSError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70448419/how-to-retry-async-requests-upon-clientoserror-errno-104-connection-reset-by)

it became apparent that I was trying/Excepting the wrong piece of code, I followed his example and no more errors!

```
async def get_parcel_details(client, sem, url):
""" Takes in an api client, semaphore, and url to get latest parcel data
    Returns a dictionary
"""
try:
    async with sem, client.get(url) as resp:
        parcel_details = await resp.json(encoding='UTF-8', content_type='application/json')
        return parcel_details

except (json.JSONDecodeError, aiohttp.client.ClientOSError, aiohttp.client.ContentTypeError,
        aiohttp.ClientResponseError, TypeError) as e:
            await asyncio.sleep(4)
            async with sem, client.get(url) as resp:
                parcel_details = await resp.json(encoding='UTF-8', content_type='application/json')

            return parcel_details
```