# Getting Connection Reset Error while connecting to Cloud SQL from Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to Cloud SQL database on GCP from Cloud Function. But I'm getting `ConnectionResetError` error for every execution. The Cloud SQL is in another project comparing to where Cloud Function is.

**CF Trigger**: HTTP

**VPC** : present between two projects

**Note**: The cloud function was working fine on another Project. The error occurred when I deployed the Cloud function to UAT environment.

Error Log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1463, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 872, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 870, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 855, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 134, in view_func
    return function(request._get_current_object())
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 114, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 20, in hello_http
    providers = dx.func1()
  File "/workspace/database.py", line 67, in func1
    with self.pool.connect() as db_conn:
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3315, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3394, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 325, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 888, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 491, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 145, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 271, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 386, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 684, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 680, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 250, in <lambda>
    return lambda crec: creator()
  File "/workspace/database.py", line 32, in getconn
    conn = connector.connect(
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/connector.py", line 154, in connect
    return connect_task.result()
  File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 458, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 403, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/connector.py", line 249, in connect_async
    return await asyncio.wait_for(get_connection(), timeout)
  File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 445, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/connector.py", line 245, in get_connection
    return await self._loop.run_in_executor(None, connect_partial)
  File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/pymysql.py", line 53, in connect
    sock = ctx.wrap_socket(
  File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 513, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1104, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1375, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129628/python-google-cloud-function-connection-reset-by-peer) but the failure there is intermittent, while in my case it is always giving that error.

Comment: You have provided a big stack trace with no matching code, which is not helpful. Since the code works in one environment but not another, provide details on the environment. A connection reset means that Cloud SQL did not like your connection and closed it. Maybe a firewall problem, maybe a protocol problem, maybe bad credentials. We can only guess.

Comment: +1 to above comment on needing the application code and environment settings. Because you mentioned it working in one environment but not the other probably means it is a configuration issue, Cloud Function must be use a VPC Connector to allow connectivity to the Cloud SQL instance if it is using Private IP address.

Comment: After talks with DevOps. It turns out that I cannot connect the two(cloud SQL and CF). Because, The VPC network on Project with Cloud Function is different from VPC network on the Project with Cloud SQL.  I didn't had that visibility.

Comment: You can probably use the Cloud SQL Connector: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-connectors